# Trying to identify a rechargeable battery

Tags: identification

Good evening.
I have just removed a rechargeable battery pack from a flashlight which is about 10 years old and no longer holds a charge.
There is only a model number printed on the battery:
CY100722 and the input charger operates at 5vDC 200ma
Can anyone please help me with establishing the output and capacity of the battery so that I can locate a compatible replacement ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Does the battery look like [this?](http://s60.radikal.ru/i168/1103/27/becb15e986a7.jpg) if not, show us a photo of the battery and flashlight. What voltage is the bulb rated for?

Comment: How many cells in battery. 3 x NiCd or 3 x NimH is most likely  - but, not certain.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you are dealing with

https://radioskot.ru/FOTO35/zamena_svincovykh_akb-1.jpg

[image]

Then [this page](https://radioskot.ru/publ/remont/zamena_svincovykh_akkumuljatorov_v_fonarjakh/4-1-0-1118) will help you.

The original battery is a 4V 800 mAh lead acid one. 
[Details here](https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/32452325744.html) and available
4V 800mAh Lead Acid Battery Rechargeable Flashlights Electric Mosquito Trap Battery 32 * 22 * ​​65mm Free Shipping.
BUT replacement with 3 x NimH as per the above webpage is strongly recommended.

https://radioskot.ru/FOTO35/zamena_svincovykh_akb-9.jpg

[image]

[image]

Comment: Russell thanks to you and to other respondents. You have perfectly identified the battery and a better solution. Interestingly, my model has blanking points for the side lighting shown in your photo. I will now switch to the 3xNimH AAA's.

Comment: @CliveB An interesting light. Probably Chinese made, but all the information on it seems to be Russian sourced. Where are you located?